# Joomla 3 как вывести список категорий в меню?

Tags: joomla, cms

[Вот](http://391000.ru/test/) есть сайт у которого создана куча категорий. 
Нужно их вывести под шапкой справа списком
В админке создал пункт меню [image: вот с такими настройками] но выводится только название пункта и ссылка из алиас.
Что я делаю не так??

Answer (score 1):

Ну и должно пункты меню выводить... вы же меню создаёте... если вам нужно вывести список категорий в шаблоне, надо использовать модуль "Articles - Categories" который выводит список выбранных категорий.